# Scrape HTML element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a small extension for Chrome. Among others, I want to scrape some text from the page I visit and store it to a variable. I am using jQuery. I have tried some solutions from other posts, but nothing seems to work.

```
<div id = "top-card" data-li-template="top_card" >
<div class="profile-top-card top-card " >
    <div class="profile-card vcard">
        <div class="profile-card vcard">
            <div class="profile-card vcard">
                .....
                    <div class="profile-card vcard">
                        <div id="profile-card vcard">
                            <div data-li-template="profile-card vcard">
                                <h1>
                                    <span class="fn">
                                        <span class="full-name" dir="auto">I WANT THIS TEXT</span>
```

My code so far is:

```
$('#personal_notes').click(function() {
chrome.tabs.query( {active: true}, function(tabs) {
var url = tabs[0].url;
var notes = document.getElementById('notes').value;
var name = $("body").find("full-name").text();
```

Any ideas or sources of info that I could use, are much appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need data from class name "full-name". So you should use `.` just before class name as a class selector in `jQuery`

```
$('#personal_notes').click(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query( {active: true}, function(tabs) {
       var url = tabs[0].url;
       var notes = document.getElementById('notes').value;

       var name = $("body .full-name").text();
       //OR you can use below one also with minor change
       var name = $("body").find(".full-name").text();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't seem to work.

I get a blank cell to my exported csv file. Any thoughts why?

Comment: @Vasilis Can you directly access text of that `full-name` in developer console of chrome?

Comment: Yes I can. You can test it too, just visit a random LinkedIn profile (https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=*)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".full-name").text();
```

No need of `body` here and `full-name` is a class so you need to use `.full-name` as the selector.

The code becomes:

```
$('#personal_notes').click(function() {
chrome.tabs.query( {active: true}, function(tabs) {
var url = tabs[0].url;
var notes = $("#notes").val(); // Changed this as well
var name = $(".full-name").text(); // Here you should use .
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

It doesn't seem to work. I'm getting an empty cell on my exported csv file.